# Find a value then copy a picture using offset

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a picture using offset but I do not get any data upon pasting.

- f.Offset(11, -8) is merged.
- I tested using f.Offset(11, -8).select on vba, then right-click copy, then paste to another sheet. I am getting the image, although not the right size.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
Set f = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="C:", LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then ' its found
                        f.Offset(11, -8).Copy
                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G10").PasteSpecial
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You do know you need to specify the type of PasteSpecial.... i.e. `PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)` or wahtever you want to do?

Comment: img is object so u need use `object.copy`. img is shape so use `shape(index).copy` method

Comment: When you copy (only) a range, it is pasted at the dimensions of the target cell. Do you want copying the range and the shape? Do you want only copying the picture in a specific place?

Comment: @FaneDuru I just need to copy the image with the same size. The destination cell is the top left most of the image.

Comment: OK. I will prepare an answer, trying to use what I can from your existing code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub Button1_ClickX()
 Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, f As Range, shp As Shape
 Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
 Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

 Set f = sh1.cells.Find(What:="C:", LookAt:=xlWhole)
 If Not f Is Nothing Then
    For Each shp In sh1.Shapes
        If shp.TopLeftCell.Address = f.Offset(11, -8).Address Then
            shp.Copy
            sh2.Paste
            With sh2.Shapes(sh2.Shapes.count)
                .top = sh2.Range("G10").top
                .left = sh2.Range("G10").left
            End With
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Dumont: Did you find some time to test the above code? If yes, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: It is working, I am trying a different approach though but can't get it to work yet.
 `If sh1.Range(shp.TopLeftCell.Address).Offset(-11, 8).Value = "C:"`

Comment: @Dumont: 1. We here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works. 2. I tried keeping your existing code logic and only adapted to make it working.  What you try can be sismpler accomplished using `If shp.TopLeftCell.Offset(-11, 8).Value = "C:" Then`. `shp.TopLeftCell` is already a `Range`...